# capitalizing titles after a city name

Tags: capitalization

Is the word "mayor" capitalized when it follows the city name?  As in, San Francisco Mayor John Doe   or San Francisco mayor John Doe?

Comment: You can finesse the question by writing *"San Francisco's Mayor John Doe"*.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the fact that a location or other proper noun precedes it, you do capitalize a title if it precedes a name.

Reference:

Rule 3

Capitalize a person's title when it precedes the name. Do not capitalize when the title is acting as a description following the name.

Examples:
Chairperson Petrov
Ms. Petrov, the chairperson of the company, will address us at noon.

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp

Comment: Well, but is "mayor" a title in this case? "Mayor" is one thing, but "San Francisco mayor" is quite another. It's just the mayor of San Francisco. Just like in your example, "Chairperson" is capitalized when it's the title, but not when it's just the chairperson of the company.