# Military and Peerage Titles

Tags: british-english, capitalization

If you are referring to a member of the peerage, I know you would capitalize Lord Matlock or the Earl of Matlock. If I am calling him the Earl and it is directly in reference to him, without the surname, would the "e" in Earl be capitalized? I know the you would not do so if referring to a group of men by that titled.

I am wondering the same with Colonel. If I refer to Colonel Fitzwilliam it is capitalized. If I refer to "the colonel" directly referencing him would the "c" be capitalized. Would it be capitalized if I address him as Colonel, but don't use his name?

Comment: Checking NGrams for [the colonel ordered](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2Cthe+colonel+ordered%2Cthe+Colonel+ordered&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20colonel%20ordered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20Colonel%20ordered%3B%2Cc0) and [the colonel asked](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+colonel+asked%2Cthe+Colonel+asked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20colonel%20asked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20Colonel%20asked%3B%2Cc0) suggests the modern trend is *not* to capitalize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [capitalizing titles after a city name](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162918/capitalizing-titles-after-a-city-name)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The 'trend' hasn't got as far as me yet. If it means a specific person, and the word is a form of address, I would capitalise. If it was *the policeman gave us directions', I wouldn't capitalise that. But perhaps if it was *the Constable spoke to the Sergeant*, I probably would. You just have to rely on your own intuition sometimes. Incidentally you are pretty close to your 100k reputation aren't you. If I'm not around when it happens - many congratulations. You should think of a way of celebrating on line!

Comment: @WS2: I absolutely agree that if used as a form of address, *Colonel* should always be capitalized (just as with [*Shoulder your weapon, Private!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22your+weapon+private%22)). But I certainly wouldn't capitalize [The private raised his rifle](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+private+raised+his%22). Would you? (That would look positively "Victorian" to me! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure I would actually say *The private raised his rifle* (with or without capitals). Does one usually use the term *private* when talking or writing about squaddies? If however there were a particular reason for referring to his rank, such as, for example *the Private who proved so capable was quickly promoted to Corporal*, what would you think of that?

Comment: @WS2: Each of my two links above encompasses many written instances. The Google Books search itself isn't case-sensitive, but it seems pretty obvious to me the vast majority of matches are capitalized as per my comment. That's to say these "rank identifiers" are always capitalized when used as a term of address, and usually when "uniquely" referencing a "third party individual", but not otherwise. I would never capitalize *private* in your example (because the "unique identifier" element is covered by *...who proved so capable*), nor *colonel* (because it's just a rank, not an identifier).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So would you write *The Private was quickly promoted to the rank of corporal.*?

Answer (score 3):

When you put a title before a name, it becomes part of the name, so it is capitalised.

Example:

I spoke to Colonel Fitzwilliam.

I daresay, I do believe that was the Earl of Matlock running naked across the pitch!

When you don't include the last name or don't use the title as the person's name, then you do not capitalise the first letter.  Saying 'the' before the title without the last name after it means that you are not using it as that person's name.

Example:

I told the earl that I wouldn't be available.

I told the Earl of Matlock that I wouldn't be available.

NOTE: In Queen's English, the only exception to this rule is when referring to the Queen, but not just any queen, only Great Britain's.

If it's easier to remember, this is the same rule you use when discussing your mum.  When you use "mum" in the place of your mum's name, you capitalise the first letter.  Otherwise, you don't.

Examples:

I'll see you later, Mum.

I told my mum that I would see her later.

The mum just stood there doing nothing as her children went completely mental.

Comment: Offhand I can't think of any Anglophone country whose queen isn't our British one, but I'd have thought if there *is* such a context, those people would capitalize when referring to their own queen. The basic point of what you're saying seems right to me though, and I think the parallel with ***mum*** is apposite.

Comment: Yes, perhaps some other queen in her own land might very well take a capital letter before her title, just as Americans will give a capital P when referring to their president, but here in England, we do not offer this courtesy to foreign heads of state, only are own.

Comment: I guess these comments depend on whether the USA fully qualifies as anglophone, and whether you consider Aretha Franklin a queen (along with [a few others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific_nicknames_in_popular_music) )

Comment: Regarding 'mum', I'm not quite sure what you mean.  It seems as if you're suggesting that I may have it backwards, but I looked it all over and everything seems as it should be.  Since I only added it in order to help clarify the matter, if it's rather muddling it instead, simply disregard what I said about 'mum'.

Comment: I think I would actually capitalise Earl if it was a specific earl. I mean, you wouldn't say 'the speaker asked the member to retract his slur on the prime minister* would you? It would have to be Speaker, Member and PM wouldn't it?

Comment: As for the PM, it depends. The rules of grammar allow for one to always use initial capital letters in 'prime minister' when it refers to Britain's own, but it by no means requires it and some style guides prohibit it. If not required to write in accordance with a specific style, then the key is to remain consistent by either always capitalising for 'prime minister' or following the rules above. As for 'member' and 'speaker', their first letters aren't capitalised, save in those circumstances described above. For example, one would not write, "The Queen asked that the Member sit down."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I'm not sure I like this business of only capitalising our own Queen or own Prime Minister. Doesn't the Prime Minister of Canada, Australia or New Zealand or for that matter of France merit similar treatment. I am not inclined to follow style guides on these things, but to do what seems to me courteous. And if that involves erring on the side of capitalising, that's what I shall do.  I can't conceive of not giving the Speaker of the House of Commons a capital S. And if you do that how can you not accord a specific Member the same treatment?

Comment: @WS2, you are a rebel and a patriot!  (...and a bit of a socialist.)  Bravo!  I would never even dream of trying to convince you to be any other way. So capitalise to your heart's content, I say.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Not sure my children would agree with you! But thank you for the good write-up.